# Node.js: should package.json be managed manually only?

Tags: node.js

Node.js: Should package.json dependencies be managed manually only or there is some tools that can automatically created dependency list for app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [require-analyzer](http://github.com/nodejitsu/require-analyzer), developed by the Nodejitsu team.

Read their fine article here: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/analyze-nodejs-dependencies-like-magic